# How to print ñ on img source in php

Tags: php, image, src

- I have images inside a folder that contains 'ñ' char like `Navideño-4.jpg.`
- I created a script to print all images but if image has ñ char it just prints  `Navide%C3%B1o-4.jpg`

Here is script:

```
function show($path){
    $files = glob($path.'*');
    natcasesort($files);
    foreach($files as $file) {
            echo ' <br/> <img src="' .  $file . '" /> <br/>';
    }
}
```

and call it like:

```
show('images/navidad/');
```

How can I show ñ char inside img source in php, I have tried urlencode,urldecode..
But had no success

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: It is PHP Version 5.2.17

Comment: Then it is possible an encoding problem. Try setting LC_ALL to utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$test="Navideño-4.jpg";
echo htmlspecialchars( $test );
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
$test = "Navideño-4.jpg";
echo utf8_decode($test);
```

or

```
$test = utf8_encode("Navideño-4.jpg");
echo utf8_decode($test);
```

Comment: Tried it And got: `<img src="images/navidad/Navide?o-4.jpg">`  and `<img src="images/navidad/NavideÃ±o-4.jpg">` ... instead of  `<img src="images/navidad/Navideñ-4.jpg">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pathinfo` and `urlencode` to display the image.

```
function show($path){
    $files = glob($path.'*');
    natcasesort($files);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file);            
        echo ' <br/> <img src="' .  $path_parts['dirname'] . '/' . urlencode($path_parts['basename']) . '" /> <br/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use utf8_decode

```
echo ' <br/> <img src="' .  utf8_decode($file) . '" /> <br/>';
```

Answer (score -3):

I just tried your code with php version 5.4.16 and it was working fine for me.

I think its your php version issue. Please check your php version with phpinfo()